How to programmatically read the schema of a GraphQL query in Java?
I am working with a GraphQL API provided by an upstream system. In my application, I need to dynamically fetch the possible values for an argument in the GraphQL query. The upstream system's team has defined an enum type for this argument, containing a list of possible values.
For example, let's say the argument is country, and the enum contains a list of countries.
How can I programmatically retrieve these enum values in Java so that I can dynamically construct my GraphQL queries?
Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:
1-Query the GraphQL schema to fetch the possible values for the country argument.
2-Use these values to dynamically construct GraphQL queries.
3-Execute the constructed queries against the GraphQL API.
I'm using the graphql-java library for handling GraphQL operations in my Java application.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

You can likely use introspection for this

This has just scratched the surface of the introspection system; we can query for enum values, what interfaces a type implements, and more

I can see some introspection classes here in the graphql-java client sources which might be a good place to start
Perhaps the IntrospectionQueryBuilder might be a starting point
I asked ChatGPT how to do this which provided the following code sample. No idea if it's hallucinating or not
import graphql.GraphQL;
import graphql.introspection.IntrospectionQuery;
import graphql.introspection.IntrospectionResultToSchema;
import graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema;
import graphql.GraphQLException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GraphQLClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String graphqlEndpoint = "http://example.com/graphql"; // Replace with your GraphQL server endpoint

        // Send an introspection query to fetch the schema
        GraphQL graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(buildGraphQLSchema(graphqlEndpoint)).build();
        String schemaJson = graphQL.execute(IntrospectionQuery.INTROSPECTION_QUERY).getData().toString();

        // Parse the schema JSON into a GraphQLSchema object
        GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = new IntrospectionResultToSchema().createSchema(IntrospectionResultToSchema.parse(schemaJson));

        // Now you can work with the GraphQLSchema object
        // For example, you can retrieve enum values for a specific type
        // Let's assume you want to get possible values for an enum field called "status" in a type called "User"
        // Replace "User" and "status" with your actual type and field names
        // This is just a sample, you need to adapt it to your schema structure

        // Replace "User" with your actual type name
        GraphQLObjectType userObjectType = graphQLSchema.getObjectType("User");

        // Replace "status" with your actual field name
        GraphQLEnumType statusEnumType = (GraphQLEnumType) userObjectType.getFieldDefinition("status").getType();

        // Now you can get the possible enum values
        List<String> enumValues = statusEnumType.getValues().stream().map(GraphQLEnumValueDefinition::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("Possible values for 'status' enum:");
        System.out.println(enumValues);
    }

    private static GraphQLSchema buildGraphQLSchema(String graphqlEndpoint) {
        try {
            // Replace "http://example.com/graphql" with your actual GraphQL server endpoint
            return GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
                    .query(GraphQLSchema.newQuery().build())
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new GraphQLException("Failed to build GraphQL schema from endpoint: " + graphqlEndpoint, e);
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the inputs, this surely helps.
